# Mongoose query return nothing when same query in command line does

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongo query which returns the correct results in the Mongo console but when the same query is performed against a Mongoose model it returns an empty array.

It's the following line which isn't working as it should:

```
query.facilities = {$in: facilities.split(',')};
```

Declare my mongoose models

```
// places
placeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    category: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'categories' }],
    facilities: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'facilities' }],
});

Place = mongoose.model('places', placeSchema);

// categories
categorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    slug: String
});

Category = mongoose.model('categories', categorySchema);

facilitiesSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
});

Facility = mongoose.model('facilities', facilitiesSchema);
```

My /places route

```
app.get('/places', function(req, res){
    var geo = req.query.geo.split(',');

    if(geo.length !== 2) {
        handleError('valid_geo_coords_required');
    }

    var limit = typeof req.query.limit !== 'undefined' ? req.query.limit : 0;
    var category = req.query.category;
    var facilities = req.query.facilities;

    var query = {
        loc: {$near: geo}
    };

    if(typeof category !== 'undefined') {
        query.category = category;
    }

    if(typeof facilities !== 'undefined') {
        query.facilities = {$in: facilities.split(',')}; <---- this causes the problem
    }

    console.log(query); // pasting this into the mongo console returns correct results

    Place.find(query).limit(limit).populate('category').populate('facilities').exec(function(err, data){

    if (err) return handleError(err);

    res.json(data);
  });
});
```

The query object is:

```
{ loc: { '$near': [ '-3.188384', '55.94772' ] }, facilities: { '$in': [ '53012d6965b5e9a35efbb215' ] } }
```

This is the query I perform in the console:

```
db.places.find({ loc: { '$near': [ '-3.188384', '55.94772' ] }, facilities: { '$in': [ '53012d6965b5e9a35efbb215' ] } })
```

and returns a valid document.

Is there something specific to Mongoose which is affecting this?

**Update**

It seems to be this line that breaks it:

```
facilities: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'facilities' }],
```

maybe because it's an array of objectId's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that query works in the Mongo shell, then the `facilities` array field of the docs in the `places` collection must contain strings and not ObjectIDs.

However, based on your schema definition for `places`, Mongoose will cast `facilities` values in your query to ObjectIDs which then don't match the docs in `places` because it contains strings.

The fix is to modify your `facilities` values in the docs of the `places` collection to be ObjectIDs instead of strings.

Comment: Yeah my ```facilities``` was an array of string, not objectIds. Thanks!